# Installing an Epson XP-435 printer on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: epson

I am trying to install an Epson XP-435 printer on Ubuntu 19.10 via USB connection.
I have tried doing the usual “add printer” following the instructions and it has installed a dot Matrix Printer driver which did not work. I have tried installing ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver) again this just prints a blank page whatever is sent to it.
Can anyone tell me how to get this printer working?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, this might help your problem. http://downloadlinux.net/2017/02/06/epson-xp-432xp-435-driver-for-ubuntu-based-oses-how-to-download-install/

Answer (score 0):

Download a driver from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule

Then add the printer again a normal way, it should pick up the correct driver.

Comment: Tried that with epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.7.7-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb and still no joy.  Thanks anyway. I am going to invest in an HP printer that does support Linux although it is a shane that I have to dispose og the Epson.

Comment: Did the driver install with no errors? Is `lsb` installed?